# Gtk+ link button to directory

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I want to write a GUI in `R` with `rtgk2` package. The user should be able to load up his data. Until now, I used `gtkEntry` so one has to type in the name of the data file to open it.

It would be better to construct some link button to the directory such that the user can search for the file and click on it to get the path of it. How is this possible?

Comment: [GtkFileChooserButton.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserButton.html)

Comment: GtkLabel has an `attributes` property you can use to set font attributes.